Unexpected rounding when printing a double value
So, I don't know C++ that well, but I think that multiplying doubles should get you the double version.
However, if you were to run this code, it will not return a decimal.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double r = 50.5;
    double z = 2550.25128788;
    cout << r * z << "\n";
        // Output: 128788
}

BUT! In a calculator (and other languages like Py) you get 128787.690038 or around that value but with decimals (I think)
Why is this happening and am I just a newbie who doesn't understand floats/doubles (also yeah I tried using a float instead of double as well and still got a int back)
Maybe this is also just computer's messing up on math, but Python doesn't mess up on it...

std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << 3.14159

By default the stream inserter for double displays six digits. As the comment by @JoopEggen suggests, you can adjust the number of digits when you need to.

The title is misleading -- there is nothing "unexpected" in the math.  Internally, the calculations are done correctly, it is your displaying of the results that are at fault.  See std::setprecision

Upon testing, C++ seems to cut off digits after the 6th in std::cout by default. To show a specific amount of digit after the decimal point, setprecision does the trick. You have to import the iomanip library to use it.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // library required for setprecision
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double r = 50.5;
    double z = 2550.25128788;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(10) << r * z << "\n";
    return 0;  //Output: 128787.6900379400
}

fixed forces fixed-point notation instead of something like an exponential answer.
setprecision(n) specifies n decimal places for the output.

Ideally, instead of testing, you should look up a reliable source. cppreference confirms that the default precision is indeed 6.

@john that's a rather small default.  It must have been selected for compatibility with float.
